# const в начале и const в конце

Tags: c++, классы, методы, const, объявление

Обясните пожалуйста для чего делаеться const в начале и const в конце, и в чем вообще разница?

```
const Cash Product::GetPrice() const { return price; }
```

Comment: Впереди, при возврате по значению - смысла не вижу, вот если бы `const Cash&`, тогда дело другое... 

А второй `const` говорит о том, что функция не меняет ничего в объекте, для которого вызывается, так что его можно вызывать и для константного объекта.

Comment: В статическом варианте это выглядит как : `static Cash const Product::GetPrice ( Product const & me ) { return me.price;}`

Answer (score 6):

Использование `const` в начале объявления метода привязывает его к типу возвращаемого значения, т.е. говорит о том, что Вы возвращаете из метода константный объект.

Когда вы используете `const` в конце объявления метода, сам метод становится константным (ничего не изменяющим в объекте) и, как следствие, доступным для вызова через константные объекты.

Answer (score 2):

Данное объявление

```
const Cash Product::GetPrice() const { return price; }
```

определяет не статическую функцию-член класса с именем `GetPrice` для классе `Product`.

Первый квалификатор `const` относится к возвращаемому значению функции, то есть к объекту типа `Cash`.

Квалификтор `const`, стоящий после списка параметров, относится к самой функции и говорит о том, что функция не изменяет объект типа `Product`, для которого она вызывается.

Например, если объект типа `Product` объявлен как константный объект, то для него нельзя вызывать не статические функции-члены-класса, которые объявлены без квалификатора `const`.

Также для не статических функций-членов класса можно указывать квалификаторы ссылок, которые определяют, для какого типа ссылки (lvalur или rvalue) на объект класса может быть вызвана соответствующая не статическая функция-член класса.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

struct Cash
{
    Cash( unsigned int value ) : value( value )
    {
    }

    unsigned int value;
};

struct Product
{
    Product( unsigned int price ) : price( price )
    {
    }

    const Cash GetPrice()  & 
    {
        std::cout << " - const Cash Product::GetPrice() & is called - ";
        return price + 10; 
    }   

    const Cash GetPrice() const & 
    {
        std::cout << " - const Cash Product::GetPrice() const & is called - ";
        return price; 
    }   

    const Cash GetPrice() const && 
    { 
        std::cout << " - const Cash Product::GetPrice() const && is called - ";
        return price; 
    }

    unsigned int price;
};

int main()
{
    const Product p1( 10 );

    std::cout << "cash" << p1.GetPrice().value << '\n';

    Product p2( 10 );

    std::cout << "cash" << p2.GetPrice().value << '\n';

    std::cout << "cash" << Product( 10 ).GetPrice().value << '\n';
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
cash - const Cash Product::GetPrice() const & is called - 10
cash - const Cash Product::GetPrice() & is called - 20
cash - const Cash Product::GetPrice() const && is called - 10
```

Так как объект `p1` является константным, то для него вызывает функция с квалификаторами `const &`.

Объект `p2` не является константным, и для него вызывается функция с квалификатором ссылки `&`.

В последнем вызове функции используется временный объект, поэтому для него вызывается функция с квалификаторами `const &&`.